# Attachments with the VersionOne API Client

Tags: c#, sdk, attachment, versionone

Could someone show some sample code that shows how one would attach an outside file to a version one request using the API Client?  Assume we already have the filename and ticket id.  I've found this done with the ObjectModel, but not any code that I could understand with the API client.

Comment: Please mark MarkoPolo's answer as accepted, it works.

Answer (score 4):

This sample attaches an rtf file to a project (scope).  You would have to change the scope to the asset of your choice (likely story or defect).  Here I have the OID, not the ID.  You could query for the ID.Number (e.g. B-1234) if that is what you have.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using VersionOne.SDK.APIClient; 

namespace SampleAttachment
{

    class Program
    {

        private static readonly string ApplicationURL = "https://myversionone/";

        private static readonly string _username = "username";

        private static readonly string _password = "passwerd";

        private static readonly bool _integrated = false;



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //string file = args[0];
            string file = @"C:\Users\MIRVIN\Desktop\Training Wheels\SampleAttachment\bin\Debug\testfile.rtf";

            if (File.Exists(file))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Uploading {0}", file);
                string mimeType = MimeType.Resolve(file);

                IMetaModel metaModel = new MetaModel(new V1APIConnector(ApplicationURL + "meta.v1/"));
                IServices services = new Services(metaModel, new V1APIConnector(ApplicationURL + "rest-1.v1/", _username, _password, _integrated));
                IAttachments attachments = new Attachments(new V1APIConnector(ApplicationURL + "attachment.img/", _username, _password, _integrated));


                //cleanjeans scope
                Oid attachmentContext = Oid.FromToken("Scope:5067", metaModel);



                IAssetType attachmentType = metaModel.GetAssetType("Attachment");

                IAttributeDefinition attachmentNameDef = attachmentType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name");

                IAttributeDefinition attachmentContentDef = attachmentType.GetAttributeDefinition("Content");

                IAttributeDefinition attachmentContentTypeDef = attachmentType.GetAttributeDefinition("ContentType");

                IAttributeDefinition attachmentFileNameDef = attachmentType.GetAttributeDefinition("Filename");



                Asset newAttachment = services.New(attachmentType, attachmentContext);

                newAttachment.SetAttributeValue(attachmentNameDef, "New Attachment");

                newAttachment.SetAttributeValue(attachmentContentDef, string.Empty);

                newAttachment.SetAttributeValue(attachmentContentTypeDef, mimeType);

                newAttachment.SetAttributeValue(attachmentFileNameDef, file);

                services.Save(newAttachment);

                //Setup and attach the payload

                string attachmentKey = newAttachment.Oid.Key.ToString();
                int buffersize = 4096;

                using (FileStream input = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {

                    using (Stream output = attachments.GetWriteStream(attachmentKey))
                    {

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

                        for (; ; )
                        {

                            int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);

                            if (read == 0)

                                break;

                            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                        }

                    }

                }

                attachments.SetWriteStream(attachmentKey, mimeType);



                Console.WriteLine("{0} uploaded", file);

            }

            else

                Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist", file);

        }

    }

        }
```

Comment: I had to change V1APIConnector to VersionOneAPIConnector and for the credentials just do 'NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();' then pass them to 'services' and 'attachments' and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hey, i have an scenario where i load the attachment from an exchange email service and get the content in a byte array, but how do i write that byte array to an attachment in V1?. Thanks.

Comment: @thunder You should be able to use the majority of the code above. Follow the same steps, first creating a container asset then streaming the content into it.  Where it says int buffersize = 4096? That should be the size of your byte array.  The line byte[] buffer = new byte{buffer size] is where you are creating the payload to be sent to VersionOne. Make sure you set the mimeType to match the proper file type.